# Timing problem between State and BlocListener Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm using `flutter_bloc` and I have a button in my `MapScreen` drawer that navigates to a `AlarmsScreen` and sends an `Event` to the bloc so that `AlarmsScreen` receives a `State` with data needed to build the UI in its `BlocListener` .
I have noticed that not always `AlarmsScreen` builds accordingly to data passed in the listener with the `State`, and after a few tries I noticed that if I press the button a tad longer (a loading bar appears on the button??) than `AlarmsScreen` always draws correctly.  This means, as the prints in the  BLocListener an Bloc confirmed, that sometimes the screen loads after the `State` has been streamed and the `BlocListener` didn't catch it as it wasn't initialised yet. To make sure I added a timer with a 200 millisecond delay to send the event and now it never fails.
The timer is just a workaround, but is there a way to read the latest state streamed by the bloc when the screen loads ? .
As always thank you very much for your time and help.
Here is the button:

```
FlatButton.icon(
                          icon: Image.asset(
                            'assets/schedulerButton.png',
                            height: 55,
                            width: 55,
                          ),
                          label: Text(
                            'Check scheduler',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          onPressed: () {
                            // TODO call LoadAlarms and navigate to SchedulerScreen
                            print('pressed');
                            cache.play('tableViewOpen.mp3');
                            BlocProvider.of<SchedulerBloc>(context)
                                .add(LoadAlarms());
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
                                        value: BlocProvider.of<SchedulerBloc>(
                                            context),
                                        child: SchedulerScreen(
                                            widget.key, widget.user),
                                      )),
                            );
                            Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                              BlocProvider.of<SchedulerBloc>(context)
                                  .add(LoadAlarms());
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

This is the screen:

```
class _SchedulerScreenState extends State<SchedulerScreen> {
  AudioCache cache = new AudioCache();

  List<Alarm> alarms = [];
  List<SchedulerCell> cells = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    cache.loadAll(['click.mp3', 'tableViewOpen.mp3', 'tableViewClose.mp3']);
    dynamic backButton =
        Platform.isIOS ? CupertinoIcons.back : Icons.arrow_back;
    dynamic addButton = Platform.isIOS ? CupertinoIcons.add : Icons.add;
    return BlocListener<SchedulerBloc, SchedulerState>(
      listener: (BuildContext context, SchedulerState state) {
        if (state is AlarmsLoaded) {
          setState(() {
            alarms = state.alarms;
            print('ShedulerListener : alarms are $alarms');
            cells = state.cells;
            print('ShedulerListener : cells are $cells');
          });
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(backButton),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                cache.play('tableViewClose.mp3');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
          title: Text(
            'Controlli tragitti',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.orange,
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                letterSpacing: 1),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(addButton),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                // TODO navigate to AddEditCheckScreen
                cache.play('tableViewOpen.mp3');
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute<AddEditCheckScreen>(
                      builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
                            value: BlocProvider.of<SchedulerBloc>(context),
                            child: AddEditCheckScreen(
                                key: widget.key,
                                isEditing: false,
                                user: widget.user),
                          )),
                );
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                BlocProvider.of<SchedulerBloc>(context).add(ClearAlarms());
                // TODO navigate to AddEditCheckScreen
                cache.play('tableViewOpen.mp3');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          itemCount: alarms.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            child: cells[index],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
@override
  Stream<Transition<ComplexEvent, ComplexState>> transformEvents(
    Stream<ComplexEvent> events,
    TransitionFunction<ComplexEvent, ComplexState> transitionFn,
  ) {
    return events.switchMap(transitionFn);
  }
```

to your Bloc class. It will execute only latest event and discard any previous events. You can use https://rxmarbles.com/ to help You understand rx concept.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. What I need is actually the latest state on the stream to be available, not the event, so when the screen loads,  it can read it in the listener. As far as I understand rx this is just what it does as opposite of normal streams that only make the streamed data available to active listeners. Bloc package dough should behave just like I need as is builds on rxdart ..

Comment: @Vincenzo I think that the problem is that you're dispatching an event and immediately pushing new route. Bloc is handled asynchronously and although you're not doing any long processing in your bloc it might not be ready yet. I would check in the Alarm screen state of Bloc and rebuild with locBuilder accordingly